# trigger mysql, 2 tables; if quantity table1=<0 get id ,then, delete the line with the same id in table2

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have two tables **product** and **specific_price**

**product** (id_product,id_supplier,id_manufacturer,quantity)

**specific_price** (id_specific_price,id_product,id_shop,id_country)

I want to make a mysql trigger.

The AIM on update or insert :

**When** the '**quantity**' of product table **is <= 0  get** the **id_product** then
**Delete** the **line** of the table specific_price **with the same id_product**

```
CREATE TRIGGER  control_on_sale_with_stock AFTER UPDATE ON product 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NEW.quantity <'1' THEN
DELETE FROM specific_price WHERE id_product=NEW.id_product
END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER  UPDATE_control_on_sale_with_stock AFTER UPDATE ON product 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NEW.quantity <'1' THEN
DELETE FROM specific_price WHERE id_product=NEW.id_product;
END IF;
END;
//

DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER  INSERT_control_on_sale_with_stock AFTER INSERT ON product 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NEW.quantity <'1' THEN
DELETE FROM specific_price WHERE id_product=NEW.id_product;
END IF;
END;
//
```

In mysql we need to configure delimiter which was a little annoying because I dind't know that.

And apparently in mysql we can't insert and update in the same trigger (I'm not sure about it).